# Spring Hateoas Exception - "No plugin found for delimiter application/json! Registered plugin."

Tags: spring, spring-hateoas, hateoas

Iam trying to consume HAL resources using hateoas client using Traverson which is recommended in spring framework.
But i am getting below exception when i tried,

**Controller:**

```
@GetMapping(path = "/some")
    public String indexes(Model model) throws URISyntaxException {
        
        Traverson traverson = new Traverson(new URI(REMOTE_SERVICE_ROOT_URI), MediaTypes.HAL_JSON);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "basic ****");
        CollectionModel<EntityModel<Employee>> employees = traverson //
                .follow("data").withHeaders(headers) //
                .toObject(new CollectionModelType<EntityModel<Employee>>() {});
        model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
        model.addAttribute("employees", employees);
        return "index";
    }
```

**Employee:**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class Employee {

    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String role;
}
```

**Resource am trying to consume is:**

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "resources": [
      {
        "key": "value",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "..."
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "first": {
      "href": "..."
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "..."
    },
    "next": {
      "href": ".."
    },
    "last": {
      "href": "..."
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 1,
    "totalElements": 3,
    "totalPages": 3,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
"trace": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No plugin found for delimiter application/json! Registered plugins: [org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal.HalLinkDiscoverer@5255d51b].\r\n\tat org.springframework.plugin.core.SimplePluginRegistry.lambda$getRequiredPluginFor$2(SimplePluginRegistry.java:140)\r\n\tat java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)\r\n\tat org.springframework.plugin.core.SimplePluginRegistry.getPluginFor(SimplePluginRegistry.java:167)\r\n\tat org.springframework.plugin.core.SimplePluginRegistry.getRequiredPluginFor(SimplePluginRegistry.java:140)\r\n\tat org.springframework.plugin.core.SimplePluginRegistry.getRequiredPluginFor(SimplePluginRegistry.java:126)\r\n\tat org.springframework.hateoas.client.LinkDiscoverers.getRequiredLinkDiscovererFor(LinkDiscoverers.java:73)\r\n\tat org.springframework.hateoas.client.Rels$LinkDiscovererRel.findInResponse(Rels.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.hateoas.client.Traverson$TraversalBuilder.getAndFindLinkWithRel(Traverson.java:418)\r\n\tat org.springframework.hateoas.client.Traverson$TraversalBuilder.traverseToExpandedFinalUrl(Traverson.java:391)\r\n\tat org.springframework.hateoas.client.Traverson$TraversalBuilder.toObject(Traverson.java:311)\r\n\tat org.springframework.hateoas.examples.HomeController.indexes(HomeController.java:88)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\r\n",
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

what could be wrong!!! error message says No plugin found for delimiter application/json!!!. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Besides the response body JSON, post the response headers. I guess the header `content-type` is `application/json` instead of `application/hal+json`

Comment: @yejianfengblue have set  headers.add("Content-Type", "application/hal+json"); in the code after header set. But still getting same exception.

Comment: @yejianfengblue yes i do see the response header coming as Content-Type: application/json . How can i resolve or set. the resource is not the one which i can control,

Comment: The most standard way is asking the resource owner to fix their response header. It doesn't make sense to return a body in HAL format while the header is not `application/hal+json`.

Comment: Workaround 1: create an intermediate web service which consumes the response and produces a response with the same body and header `content-type: application/hal+json`.

Comment: Workaround 2: dive into the Spring source code and see where you can add an so-called `plugin` to handle HAL format JSON with content type `application/json`.

Comment: Workaround 3: Because I see the Traverson constructor must have a URI, which means you can't modify the header before pass response to Traverson. Or you create your own class which has similar functions of Traverson and accepts response as argument. So that you can modify response header before use that class.

Comment: @yejianfengblue so i think its not possible to consume an app/json response using traverson even though the json output is an hal/json. Am i right?